# Укоротить/упростить функцию PHP

Tags: php

Функция `check` принимает 2 массива:

1. Товары с количеством на складе
2. Выбранные склады

Результатом ее выполнения должно быть:
`true`, если все товары присутствуют хоть в одном из выбранных складов.
`false`, если хоть один товар из массива не находиться не в одном из выбранных складов

[Живой пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d58d97a093d2a0d4f5e28be07b02dcbf75733c4)

Уверен что можно проще как то это все сопоставить, но кроме как переборами я не придумал, какие есть альтернативы?

```
check($params, array $restrictionParams,)
{

    $goodStore = null;

    foreach ($params['ITEMS_STORE'] as $itemId => $stores) {
        foreach ($stores as $arStore) {
            if ($arStore['PRODUCT_AMOUNT'] > 0) {
                $goodStore[$arStore['ELEMENT_ID']][$arStore['ID']] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    $check = null;

    foreach ($restrictionParams['AVAIL_STORE'] as $needId) {
        foreach ($goodStore as $itemId => $arStore) {
            if(array_key_exists($needId, $arStore)) {
                $check[$itemId][$needId] = true;
            }else{
                $check[$itemId][$needId] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($check as $itemId => $Store) {
        if(in_array(true, $Store)) {
            $check[$itemId] = true;
        }else{
            $check[$itemId] = false;
        }
    }

    if (in_array(false,$check)) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: если писать не `if( x == expr) { $y = true; } else { $y = false}` а `$y = ($x == expr)` , то ваш код уже сильно укротится.

Comment: @teran а как если мне нужно собрать массив? можете пример дать на одном выражении?

Comment: `return in_array();` или `$check[$itemId] = in_array()` а не вот эти вот ифы. и `check[itemId][needId] = array_key_exists()`

Comment: а еще вы в начале перебираете вложенные массивы двойным циклом, и формируете все такой же вложенный массив. хотя по факту вложенный вам не нужен, ибо ведь не важно, на каком складе присутствует, главное что присутствует в принципе.

Comment: хотя наверное я не правильно понял задачу. приведите упрощенную структуру массива, без лишних полей. напишите на примерах данных, когда следует вернуть истину/ложь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то мне кажется, что Ваш код не соответствует описанию. Но возможно я описание не правильно понял.
А Ваш код (функцию) можно сократить до такого вида:

```
function check($params, array $restrictionParams)
{
    foreach ($params['ITEMS_STORE'] as $itemId => $stores) {
        foreach ($stores as $arStore) {
            if ($arStore['PRODUCT_AMOUNT'] > 0 
                && in_array($arStore['ID'], $restrictionParams['AVAIL_STORE'])
            ) {
                //хотя бы один товар нашелся, посему можно следующий ITEMS_STORE смотреть
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        
        // в текущем ITEMS_STORE отсутствуют товары с перечня AVAIL_STORE,
        // что не удовлетворяет условию задачи, посему нету смысла дальше продолжать
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Ссылка на сандбокс с добавленной этой функцией (check2) для теста - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33f58a5fed9ba3e70ea440b3cf56ce30a8ca2674

Comment: Вроде все ок, разные наборы вхождений попробовал, все работает